# pagination with search results in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've implemented a user model and I have a simple search form for 
searching by gender, age, location. I'm using the paginator to 
paginate the results. The problem is that it's only remembering the 
search criteria on the first page. When I click on page 2, or next 
etc.. It defaults back to searching all users.

Here's my dirty search code in my controller, basically it just checks 
the submitted form fields and does a query on the matching field in 
the Users table and then paginates the results:

```
if (!empty($this->data)) { 
    // by name 
    if (!empty($this->data['User']['search_name'])) { 
  $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array('visible'=>1, 
'OR'=>array( 
                'User.username LIKE' => '%'.$this->data['User']['search_name'].'%', 
                'User.firstname LIKE' => '%'.$this->data['User']['search_name'], 
                'User.lastname LIKE' => '%'.$this->data['User']['search_name']) 
                 ), 'limit'=>'10', 'order'=>'User.username'); 
   } 
   // by gender 
   else if (!empty($this->data['User']['search_gender'])) { 
  $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array( 
  'visible'=>1, 
                'User.gender' => $this->data['User']['search_gender'] 
                ), 'limit'=>'10', 'order'=>'User.username'); 
  } 
  // by state 
  else if (!empty($this->data['User']['search_state'])) { 
  $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array( 
  'visible'=>1, 
                'User.state' => $this->data['User']['search_state'] 
                ), 'limit'=>'10', 'order'=>'User.username'); 
  } 

   // Send the results for the above criteria to the view 
   $results = $this->paginate('User'); 
   $this->set('users', $results); 

     } 
     // Default retrieval of all users 
    else { 
        $this->paginate = array('conditions'=>array('visible'=>1), 
'limit'=>'10', 'order'=>'User.username'); 
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate('User')); 
  }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make subsequent pages of the 
pagination remember my search criteria. Thanks for any help.

Comment: We can do it with Post method also with help of session, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332714/pagination-links-breaking-search-results-coming-from-post-data-cakephp/25946799#25946799

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$this->data` is empty on the 2nd page as it's populated by posting your search form (which isn't posting to the 2nd page).

Change your search form post to a GET ( `$this->Form->create('ModelName', array('type'=>'get')` ) and parse `$this->params` instead of `$this->data`

Comment: Superb! Works for me also. :) +1